# How can use as code?

Tags: c#

hi I wrote allready a working code;

```
private void baslangic_gridler(UIElement element)
    {
        DoubleAnimation opaklk = new DoubleAnimation();
        opaklk.From = 0;
        opaklk.To = 1;
        opaklk.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);


        Thickness to_margin = (element as Grid).Margin;
        Thickness from_margin = to_margin;


        from_margin.Left = from_margin.Left - 25;
        ThicknessAnimation kaydır = new ThicknessAnimation();
        kaydır.From = from_margin;
        kaydır.To = to_margin;
        kaydır.Duration = new TimeSpan(00,0,0,0,300);


        element.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, kaydır);
        element.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, opaklk);
    }
```

but I want to use all type of forms element like button or image

```
Thickness to_margin = (element as Grid).Margin;
```

what can I use instead of grid for all the elements?

Comment: I've already given an answer but please note that for future questions you should tag what type of app you are working with (i.e. winforms, wpf, uwp, etc...). You should also edit this question to include that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties), the `Grid` class (System.Windows.Controls) inherits it's `Margin` property from `FrameworkElement` so you should use that to cover all your bases.

> Margin: Gets or sets the outer margin of an element.(Inherited from FrameworkElement.)

Note that a `FrameworkElement` *is a* `UIElement` so you could just take the `FrameworkElement` as the parameter to your method instead of the `UIElement` like so:

```
private void baslangic_gridler(FrameworkElement element)
{
    DoubleAnimation opaklk = new DoubleAnimation();
    opaklk.From = 0;
    opaklk.To = 1;
    opaklk.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);


    Thickness to_margin = element.Margin;
    Thickness from_margin = to_margin;


    from_margin.Left = from_margin.Left - 25;
    ThicknessAnimation kaydır = new ThicknessAnimation();
    kaydır.From = from_margin;
    kaydır.To = to_margin;
    kaydır.Duration = new TimeSpan(00,0,0,0,300);


    element.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, kaydır);
    element.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, opaklk);
}
```